# Align div vertically with text

Tags: css, html, alignment

How can I position a `display:inline-block` `div` to be vertically aligned with text ?

See my example:
http://jsfiddle.net/T5W7P/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T5W7P/3/

Answer (score 2):

do you mean this?

```
#divus{
width:20px;
height: 20px;
border: 1px solid red;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
```

}